# Explanation of right to left binary method of modular arithmetic?

Tags: algorithm, modular-arithmetic

I have been studying this link from wikipedia of modulo of a large number, Here is the pseudocode.

```
function modular_pow(base, exponent, modulus)
    result := 1
    while exponent > 0
        if (exponent mod 2 == 1):
           result := (result * base) mod modulus
        exponent := exponent >> 1
        base = (base * base) mod modulus
    return result
```

I don't understand the explanation given in wiki.Why I have to check if exp%2 is even or odd. also why I am doing the three operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This algorithm is a combination of the [*Exponentiation by Squaring*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm and modulo arithmetic.

To understand what's going on, first consider a situation when `exponent` is a power of `2`. Then, assuming that `exponent = 2 ^ k`, the result could be computed by squaring the result `k` times, i.e.

```
res = (...((base ^ 2) ^2 ) ... ) ^2))
              ---------------------
                     k times
```

When `exponent` is not a power of `2`, we need to make additional multiplications. It turns out that if we can divide `exponent` by 2 without remainder, we can square the base, and divide the exponent. If, however, there is a remainder, we must additionally multiply the intermediate result by the value of the current `base`.

What you see is the same exponentiation by squaring applied to modulo multiplication. The algorithm denotes integer division by two using the `exponent >> 1` operation, which is identical to `floor(exponent / 2)`.