# Calculating and printing (2^N-1) mod (10^9 + 7) for large N in C

Tags: c, math

I have a certain problem where I'm given a list of T numbers (T is the first line of the input) called N, and I must print out `((2^N)-1)%(10^9+7)` for each of the numbers. The following constraints apply:

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 100
1 ≤ N ≤ 100000000
```

I'm getting the right answer for low integers, but not for high ones. I think it has something to do with the `pow()` function in math.h but I'm unsure.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int t, i;
    long long unsigned int ans, n, m = 1000000007;
    scanf("%u", &t);
    for (i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
        scanf("%llu", &n);
        ans = ((long long unsigned int)pow(2,n)-1)%m;
        printf("%llu\n", ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So basically when I give my program this input:

```
6
1
2
3
4
5
100000000
```

I get the output:

```
1
3
7
15
31
582344007
```

The first 5 lines of my output are correct but I want to get 494499947 for the last line.

[See here for the wolfram alpha output which gives the correct answer.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%282%5E100000000%29-1%29%25%2810%5E9%2B7%29)

Sorry if my question is trivial, I'm still learning the details of C.

Comment: Related: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19839709/335858)

Comment: The number 2^100million would require nearly 12MB of memory to be allocated. Then you try to dump that in a `long long`... LOL

Comment: @Havenard Yeah kinda stupid of me xD I see my mistake now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of `pow(2, 100000000)` is over 30 million digits long. It cannot be converted to an integer type (even `long long unsigned int`) - it's way too big!

You will need to use [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) to get an accurate result here.

Comment: Looking at the bottom of the wikipedia page, I found that Python already has modular exponentiation built-in with its pow function. I wrote my solution up in 7 lines of Python and the code finished in 0.00 time. :P Kinda lazy of me but bleh :D The code was still super fast.

Answer (score 1):

**Your approach is time consuming as well  overflowing the size 2^64 (long long).** 
As said in your question you want to find 2^100000000. It'll take "100000000" these many iterations precisely *O(n)*.
So better approach would be using modular exponentiation. 
Not  only it calculates in *O(log n)* time but also gives  answer in integer(long long) range by using mod 10^9+7 at intermediate steps.

```
   mod=10^9+7;


 powermod(x,y)
         res:=1
             while(y>0)
                 if y&1
                    res=res*x%mod

                x=x*x%mod
                y=y>>1
         return res
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling pow, which takes a double. If you want maximum range, at least use powl on Linux, which takes a long double.
Your program is missing checks for overflow, range errors, etc. If (as seems) you're interested in correctness of your results, then you should add these.
I think you just need to re-read 'man pow' more closely :-)

Comment: While a long double has *slightly* more precision than a normal double on some platforms, it's still nowhere near enough for this. (Even on a platform with 128-bit long doubles, it still has only 30 – 33 digits of precision, where this application would require 30 **million**.)

Comment: Precisely, hence 'at least' :-) Although at some point the OP is going to need arbitrary-precision arithmetic, there's no reason not to use the precision that the hardware offers, in order to delay that point as long as possible.